# Column 0 error while trying to build the code in clearcase dynamic view

Tags: makefile, build-process, clearcase

I have been trying to build the code present in a dynamic view. I use **clearmake.exe all** command while trying to build the code. The issue here is that when I am building my code in Windows 2003 server, the build is successful, where as, when I am building the same code in Windows 2008 R2 server, the compilation fails with the following syntax error :

**Clearmake.exe: Error: Syntax error in file “makefile”, line 2, column 0**.

I could have very well debugged my makefile if there is a column 0. I strongly believe this is not related to the makefile script. Can someone help me here? I am completely stumped and helpless.

**Note :**

1) The Cygwin version I am using in Windows 2003 environment is 1.90.4.1 and the one I am using in Windows 2008 R2 environment is 2.6.0.

2)The clearcase version I am using in Windows 2003 environment is 8.0.0.15 and the one we are using in Windows 2008 R2 environment is 8.0.0.7.

Comment: What version of ClearCase are you using? @VonC's APAR link about the trailing newline is for a decade old issue that was resolved in 2006. If it's back, that's a good thing to know...

Comment: Ooops ! Forgot to mention that ! I have edited my question for a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Check for any special characters or eol (end-of-line) discrepancies between the two makefiles.
For instance, a "`syntax error column 0`" appear here:

- "[ClearMake should ignore multibyte characters in comments fields](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC39619)"
- "[CLEARMAKE REPORTS A SYNTAX ERROR WHEN THE MAKEFILE DOES NOT END WITH A "`\N`"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK21252)"

The last one has an obvious solution:

> Workaround:
>   Customer is working around this issue by adding a newline character to the end of his makefile.

Comment: The APAR you linked is about a decade old, referring to the 2006C patch bundle. I guess it's possible that @Coding Ninja is using CC 2003.06.00, but I would hope not at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have more questions than answers:

1. Why is the newer environment using the older CC release?
2. Is the makefile generated by something from Cygwin? Otherwise the Cygwin version isn't really an issue.

It really can't be related to anything BUT the makefile. If the makefile is generated by something cygwin-based before clearmake sees it, it coud be there. If it is literally the same version of the same makefile (in other words, if the makefile is under source control and NOT generated by the build environment and the views select the same version) then it would most likely be an issue with the makefile parser.

Comment: I have noticed your first point when I was trying to answer your first comment. I have raised this issue with my seniors and will get back ASAP. May be mere upgradation of clearcase could help !!